# Tramp and non-existent directories

Tags: tramp, directory

When I create a new file in a (currently) non-existent directory, the echo area displays:

```
Use M-x make-directory RET RET to create the directory and its parents
```

which I plan on doing as soon as skeletons, etc. are inserted.  However, before I have a chance to do so, Tramp decides to make an uninvited entrance:

```
Password for /sudo:root@localhost:
```

and the only way to stop it from asking is to use `C-g`.

Is there any way to tell Tramp to stop doing this?  I don't want to disable Tramp entirely (though I think I did do this at one point until I needed Tramp for something).

My `.emacs.d` can be found [here](https://github.com/ivan-m/.emacs.d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tramp must check whether the directory, you intend to create the new file in, does exist. This can be done only by checking on the remote host. Asking for the password is part of the connection to the remote host.

Comment: Except that there is no remote host as it's local.  Is it possible to have tramp skip checking sub-directories of `$HOME`?

Comment: If Tramp asks for a password there is a reason. Could you pls show a scenario how it happens, starting with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: I've worked it out: I had the defadvice from this blog post which was causing the problems; an altered version in the comments seems to fix it though: http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/04/21/edit-files-as-root/